# How to create blank-space between UICollectionView and UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

I am having some difficulties trying to resolve this matter.

I have added a `UIView` which transforms in size using `CGAffineTransform` and its `scale` method. (When a button is tapped).

On the iPhone 6, 6s, 7 and 7S, the layout it completely fine.

However, when I use the iPhone 5 simulator or the iPhone SE the `UIView` covers the `UICollectionView` to an extent.

Pay no attention to the button in the bottom-right corner. I simply forgot to hide it.

[image: This is the issue]

How can I make it so that this is not the case and the `UIView` is shown with all elements always under the `UICollectionView`? Without overlapping?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you want it to look like before and after the transform. E.g. Do you want the collection view to take up as much space as it can before the transform and then shrink a bit so it doesn't overlap after the transform? I'm be inclined to see if I could do what was needed solely with constraints with `@IBOutlet` for the constraint whose `constant` I want to tweak and see if we could do everything with constraints. But it's hard to get specific without knowing better what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: set your collection view size as per device size

Comment: @Rob I'm an idiot mate. I forgot to mention I am using CGAffine.scale() and my y co-ordinate is set to -69 (which on the iPhone 6S) is the distance between the UICollectionView and the View. Hence why it overlaps. I am trying to get the bottom constraint of the UICollectionView however, I run into an error. Cannot connect repeat etc. I do not wish to tweak the CollectionView rather the view (dark area) to adjust itself. And ensure all elements within the view are shown regardless of the device.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a simple trick using auto-layout.
Pull a reference outlet of your collectionView's **Bottom constraint** and increase or decrease it according to the size of your View to put your View to the bottom of your collectionView

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did this, however, I got the error, as I'm sure you'd be familiar with. Something regarding repeat content? With the UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the issue. This method may seem like a "cop-out".

However, what I did was, redesign the view on an iPhone SE interface and this helped solve the issue. I was subtracting -69 from the scale, I figured I need to subtract a max of -39.